# Managing nested dependent data in Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have a JSON object which contains `models` array. Each model contain `params` array and each param contain `values`. `values` should displayed on page as radiobuttons or selects and user can choose it. I need to build HTML so that if user chooses the value then variable `selectedValues` keeps object like this `{param_id: value_id, another_param_id: another_value_id}` e.t.c. This variable should show what values for which parameters selected by the user. The problem is i don't know how many params and how many value will come - it's fully dynamic JSON, generated by server.

**Demo fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/z68tx53c/1

Comment: @Dandy please see updated answer

Comment: code above throws
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return selectedModel().params }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return alias =='material' }"
Message: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return values }"
Message: Unable to process binding "checked: function (){return $root.selectedValues()[$parent.id] }"
Message: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `selectedValues()[1]` when `selectedValues()` is null (which you are, before it's populated), you will get this error: `Cannot read property '1' of undefined` . Wrap the html which uses `selectedValues`  in a `with` or `if` binding, so that the containing nodes are only there when selectedValues is non null.

Comment: `selectedValues` don't populated by the server, it contains ids of values, chosen by user. It's quite misunderstanding, so i'll try to make a jsfiddle for this.

Comment: Yes. There is another JSON populated by server, which contains `params` and `values` inside each param. User can select `values` and i need some sort of "matrix" in `selectedValues` where param.id corresponds to value.id, selected by user.

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/z68tx53c/1/
i wrote some comments to fully introduce my problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z68tx53c/2/ to show you what I mean. I wrapped the html which uses selectedValues in an 'if' binding, so that the containing nodes are only there when selectedValues is non null.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand how this can solve my problem. All i trying to do is assign `selectedValues[$parent.id]` from HTML. And as you can see from `<h3 data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(selectedValues)"></h3>` - it doesn't work

Comment: You need brackets on that. `ko.toJSON(selectedValues())`